# What is the difference between front-page.php and home.php?

Tags: theme-development

When developing a theme wordpress grant us to use front-page and home page templates, so what is the major difference between these two templates as they seems like identical. I also want to know what will be the purpose of index.php file if we have front-page.php or home.php to work like our main index file, I mean server accepts the index file to index as main page or home page so if we name the file front-page or home how it will possible for site indexing.

Comment: this is a good place to start: [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In short:

- `index.php` is a fallback template only, in case no appropriate template was found
- `home.php` is used for the blog (a listing of recent posts)
- `front-page.php` is used for the landing-page

## The universal `index.php` template

The `index.php` template file is a fallback template. It is used as a last resort when no other more appropriate template is available. For example, if you don't have a `front-page.php` nor a `home.php` then `index.php` will be used. This is also true for missing `archive.php` or `single.php` and so on.

## Regarding `front-page.php` VS `home.php`

Now the difference between `front-page.php` and `home.php` templates is that the `front-page.php` is used, as its name suggests, as the main front-page of the site, while `home.php` is intended to be the home of the **Blog** section.

### What template will be used for my site's landing-page?

The `front-page.php` template, if present, will be used for the site's main front page (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`). If not present, then `home.php` will be used instead. If both the `front-page.php` and `home.php` template files are missing then the `index.php` fallback template will be used.

### What template will be used for my blog page?

WordPress allows you to have a "Blog" page (which will list recent posts) on a *different page* than the landing-page (e.g. `http://www.example.com/blog/`). So if this is the case on your site, then the Blog page will always use the `home.php` template. If `home.php` doesn't exist then the `index.php` fallback template will be used.

## How to configure the landing-page and blog page?

To configure what content to show on your front page, go to the **WordPress Admin**, under **Tools > Reading**, there you can configure the "*Front page displays*" to show a static page, or your latest posts.

In the case you choose to display a static page on the front page, then you also have the possibility to set which page to use as a placeholder for the Blog page (which will use the `home.php` template):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7tOM.png]

More technical details are available in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).